# Double click event for List box

Tags: javascript, html

Can a list box have double click event on its items?

Comment: lol i read lisp box... need to sleep

Answer (score 5):

Yes: [MSDN DHTML Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536921(VS.85).aspx).  Since your tags say javascript and HTML I am assuming you are talking about a Select element.

```
<select ondblclick = "handler" ... >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try create links with select options. Links support ondblclick event.

http://www.irt.org/articles/js058/#6

JavaScript 1.2
JavaScript 1.2 is supported by Netscape Navigator 4.0. Although Microsoft Internet Explorer appears to support JavaScript 1.2, it actually implements a different Dynamic Object Model

Object  Event Handlers
select  onBlur(), onChange(), onFocus()

area    onDblClick(), onMouseOut(), onMouseOver()

link    onClick(), onDblClick(), onKeyDown(), onKeyPress(), onKeyUp(), onMouseDown(), onMouseOut(), onMouseUp(), onMouseOver()

Answer (score -2):

ListBox controls raise this (at least in Windows Forms) - here is a link that might help get you started, and includes some sample code for hooking to a ListBox's DoubleClick event:

[Control.DoubleClick Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doubleclick.aspx)

Comment: Since downvote was uncommented: The OP explictly tagged the question as javascript - so he talks about html listboxes and javascript event handler. Not Windows Forms